# php mysql query | html table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Guys I am confused now the populated data in the table is not showing the first record

[image]

html table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
                            <tr bgcolor="#009933">
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Course</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Grade</td>
                            <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            while($result= mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".$result['stud_name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$result['grade']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$result['remark']."</td>";
                            }
                            ?>
</table>
```

and this is the query:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_grade WHERE instructor_id = '$inst_id' AND term = '$term' AND description = '$desc'");
```

But when I test the query using json it shows all the records

```
{
    "test": [{
        "stud_name": "Jeo De Jesus",
        "grade": "58",
        "remark": "Failed"
    }, {
        "stud_name": "Juana Gonzales",
        "grade": "60",
        "remark": "Failed"
    }, {
        "stud_name": "Wendy Lizardo",
        "grade": "81",
        "remark": "Passed"
    }, {
        "stud_name": "Jeffrey Oliveras",
        "grade": "91",
        "remark": "Passed"
    }, {
        "stud_name": "Mc Jester Salinas",
        "grade": "83",
        "remark": "Passed"
    }],
    "success": 1
}
```

Comment: Okay I solve it ^_^ it is related to this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318302/first-row-from-mysql-query-result-not-being-displayed

Comment: The problem might be that you are using mysql_* which is depreciated in older versions and removed from new php version so try using mysqli or PDO and in order to omit sql injection risk use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not closing your . try with this.(Not tested)

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" align="center" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr bgcolor="#009933">
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Name</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Course</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Grade</td>
                        <td align="center" style="color:#FFF;">Remark</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        while($result= mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$result['stud_name']."</td>";
                            echo "<td class=\"text-center\">"."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$result['grade']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$result['remark']."</td></tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Can you share you mysql_fetch_array($query1) result

Comment: Omitting a `</tr>` end tag is not an error. It cannot cause problems.

Comment: I think you are executing sql before the mysql_fetch_array($query1). Please share your all code. so we can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the `<tr>` tag inside the while loop. I am not sure whether it can solve your problem, but it was not right.

Comment: as you suggested sir I closed it but still nothing's changed :(

Comment: Omitting a `</tr>` end tag is not an error. It cannot cause problems.